# how to create good looking tables in UWP with Microsoft graph data

Tags: listview, user-interface, uwp, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to present data I present from O365 graph to the end user. The data I retrieve is returned to me in a JSON Array. I want to present the data in a table like from to the user. On one page there should be several tables. I have been trying many things but I'm unable to find something that looks good. I'm using the below xaml code to fill a list view from a list created from the returned json. Technically this works fine. It only does not look good. Anyone has any tips on how to create a good looking table in uwp?

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="10,100,0,0">
            <Button x:Name="btnActivationCounts" Content="Activation Counts" Click="btnActivationCounts_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnActivity" Content="Workload Activity" Click="btnActivity_Click"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnActivityTeams" Content="Team Activity" Click="btnActivityTeams_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <!--Start of the office product activation list-->
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Width="850" Height="500" Margin="0,10,10,0" Background="{ThemeResource  SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}">
            <ListView x:Name="lstActivationResults" Margin="50, 10, 10, 0">
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column ="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Product" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Android" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="ios" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Windows" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Windows10 Mobile" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Mac" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="6" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Date" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListLowBrush}" BorderBrush="Silver">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding productType}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding android}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding ios}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding windows}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding windows10Mobile}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding mac}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="6" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding reportDate}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />

                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            </ListView>
        </Canvas>
        <!-- start of the major worload activities list-->
        <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Width="850" Height="500" Margin="0,10,10,0" Background="{ThemeResource  SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}">

            <ListView x:Name="lstActivity" Margin="15, 10, 10, 0">
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column ="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Office365" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Exchange" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="OneDrive" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="SharePoint" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Skype" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Yammer" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="6" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Teams" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="7" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Date" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListLowBrush}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding office365}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding exchange}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding oneDrive}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding sharePoint}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding skypeForBusiness}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="5" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding yammer}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="6" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding teams}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="7" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="7" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding reportDate}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />

                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            </ListView>
        </Canvas>

        <!-- Start of the listview that will show the activity for teams-->
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="850" Height="500" Margin="0,10,10,0" Background="{ThemeResource  SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}">
            <ListView x:Name="lstActivityTeams"  Margin="50, 10, 10, 0">
                <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="0" Width="600" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListMediumBrush}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column ="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="ChatMessages"  Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="PrivateChatMessages"  Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Calls"  Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Meetings"  Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Date"  Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                            </Border>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid RowSpacing="0" Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundListLowBrush}" BorderBrush="Silver" Width="600" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding teamChatMessages}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding privateChatMessages}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding calls}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="3" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 0 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding meetings}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="3 3 3 3">
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding reportDate}"/>
                            </Border>

                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />

                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            </ListView>
        </Canvas>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Telerik has a grid control in their controls which might be what you are looking for.  the controls are open source https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui https://www.telerik.com/blogs/telerik-ui-for-uwp-now-open-source

Comment: Thanks Ken. That looks useful. I have seen it before but first wanted to give it a go with pure Microsoft code. I will also try the telerik solution.

Comment: I used this one in a project once https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid